# How to fix "TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable" using pyShp in python3

Tags: python, typeerror, geojson, shapefile, pyshp

I'm currently using pyShp to convert a shapefile into a geojson file. I saw a lot of people using the same script as me but i trully don't know why it's not working on my computer. I have the same error again and again but i don't understand where it comes from.

```
import shapefile
from json import dumps

   # read the shapefile
reader = shapefile.Reader("my.shp")
fields = reader.fields[1:]
field_names = [field[0] for field in fields]
buffer = []
for sr in reader.shapeRecords():
    atr = dict(zip(field_names, sr.record))
    geom = sr.shape.__geo_interface__
    buffer.append(dict(type="Feature", geometry=geom, properties=atr)) 

   # write the GeoJSON file

geojson = open("pyshp-demo.json", "w")
geojson.write(dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": buffer}, indent=2) + "\n")
geojson.close()
```

Here is the output I got :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-f2d1179eb9c9> in <module>()
     15 
     16 geojson = open("pyshp-demo.json", "w")
---> 17 geojson.write(dumps({"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": buffer}, indent=2) + "\n")
     18 geojson.close()

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    237         separators=separators, default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys,
--> 238         **kw).encode(obj)
    239 
    240 

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
--> 201             chunks = list(chunks)
    202         return ''.join(chunks)
    203 

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    428             yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
    429         elif isinstance(o, dict):
--> 430             yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
    431         else:
    432             if markers is not None:

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    402                 else:
    403                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 404                 yield from chunks
    405         if newline_indent is not None:
    406             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_list(lst, _current_indent_level)
    323                 else:
    324                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 325                 yield from chunks
    326         if newline_indent is not None:
    327             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    402                 else:
    403                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 404                 yield from chunks
    405         if newline_indent is not None:
    406             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    402                 else:
    403                     chunks = _iterencode(value, _current_indent_level)
--> 404                 yield from chunks
    405         if newline_indent is not None:
    406             _current_indent_level -= 1

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    435                     raise ValueError("Circular reference detected")
    436                 markers[markerid] = o
--> 437             o = _default(o)
    438             yield from _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    439             if markers is not None:

/usr/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    178         """
    179         raise TypeError("Object of type '%s' is not JSON serializable" %
--> 180                         o.__class__.__name__)
    181 
    182     def encode(self, o):

TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

Normally I'm supposed to have a correct geojson file.

If you're able to help me thank you very much :)

Comment: Is `geom` in bytes I think thats the problem, Show the type of that variable. Also what about `field_names` and `sr.record`

Comment: @Yashik i did a ```type(geom) ``` and it's a dict, ```field_name``` is a list and ```sr.record``` is a ```shapefile._Record```

Comment: if an error like this happens to me I will try to change it to string type and will look if the error is gone. You can do this by surrounding `str()` on `field_names`,`sr.record`, and `geom`

Comment: I tried but i got this error now                                                                       ```File "<ipython-input-7-9f820b2fccb2>", line 7
    str(field_names) = [field[0] for field in fields]
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function calll```

Comment: Do this `str(field[0])`.

Comment: unfortunatly it doesn't work : ```TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable``` maybe i should find another way to convert my file but honnestly everybody i saw on the web using this script where happy i'm loosing hope

Comment: Okay how about trying this one last time `str(buffer)` on the second last line and remove all other `str()`

Comment: The code is understanding ```buffer``` as a ```bytes``` object but i checked and it's just a ```list```

Comment: It is what is inside the list

Comment: `str(buffer)` if that doesn't work. Tell me

Comment: I think it worked with ```str(buffer)```

Comment: It is because there is bytes inside the buffer list

Comment: You could analyze which data is in bytes and decode it

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
#.....

buffer = []
reader.encoding = "latin1"

#......
```

It was from the encoding.
[More details](https://gist.github.com/frankrowe/6071443) on this error.